# Decimal? to string removing trailing zero's C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have tried to do this conversion(decimal? to string) using information from few similar posts, but somehow failed("G29"; replace("0,00","")...) so what would be the best way to transform 91,5M decimal? to string so that we would have 91,5?

```
    string a;
    decimal? number = 91.5M;
    a =  number.ToString();
```

in this example a = 91.5 and everything is fine. But for some strange reason when I get a bunch of objects from Oracle db and try to convert them to this specific format without trailing zeros, I just can't find a way to do this, because always the final output is 91,50 instead of 91,5

Comment: Well let's see the code where you are getting the objects from Oracle. The code you've shown is not where the problem is, so it's largely irrelevant.

Comment: How are those "objects" defined in Oracle (what is the exact column type)?

Comment: Also worthy of note is that you should be checking these objects for null, before accessing them ...

Comment: coalesce(column, 0) rocks if problem is with an entry from DB

Comment: string a =string.Format("{0:F1}", number); this is what has worked for me

Comment: Oracle rounds the numbers and after transformation to c# aditional 0's stays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *specifically* want up to one decimal position with no leading zeros, you can try this:

```
string str = number.ToString("0.#");
```

Adding more `#` will increase precision, but result will not contain non-significant digits.
Replace `#` with `0` in case you have to keep trailing zeroes.

You also can specify the format for the separator, with a second `IFormatProvider` parameter:

```
string str = number.ToString("0.#", fr-FR); // 5 => 5   5,123 => 5,1 (comma)
string str = number.ToString("0.#", en-US); // 5 => 5   5,123 => 5.1 (dot)
```

Comment: "Replace # with 0 in case you have to keep trailing zeroes." works perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = number.ToString("G29");
```

This should remove your trailing zeroes in the output string. There is a potential flaw in this in as much as very small values will be represented "xEx" format. Not sure if this is a problem for you.